# Movie with a living bioengineered fur coat collar that would purr when stroked

Tags: story-identification, movie

My mother and I both vividly remember a particular scene of an old Science-Fiction movie but neither of us remembers anything else about that movie.

In the scene a woman was wearing a kind of fur coat collar that was actually a living bioengineered organism. The collar did not have eyes or anything. It was just a long piece of fur. When it was stroked it purred like a cat would.

We can not remember anything else about the movie except that it was likely from before the nineties.

Comment: I think this may be a scene from "Brazil"

Comment: [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6zVHwFA0a0) Its these furs I was thinking of but they don't speak in this scene!

Comment: We watched Brazil and that wasn't it, but thanks for the suggestion. I had already seen Brazil in the past, but it was still pleasant to watch it again.